# Determine the height of a triangle by given cathetus and hypotenuse for two similarity triangles

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

The length of the drawn through lines are given. Is there a way to determine $h_b$ ? The angle $\alpha$ is unknown, but can be assumed to be small.

[image]

My approach so far was to to consider $\sin(\alpha) \approx \tan(\alpha) \Rightarrow \frac{h_b-x}{a}= \frac{h_b}{b}$, and $h_b-x=h_a$, leading to $h_b= \frac{x}{1-\frac{a}{b}}$.  How to continue? Is there an elementary way to solve this?

Comment: Is $b$ the whole side or just up to $h_a$?

Comment: $b$ is the whole side

Answer (score 1):

$hyp_a = \sqrt{a^2 + h_a^2}$

Then $\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + h_a^2}}=\frac{h_b}{h_a}$

Hence $h_b = \frac{bh_a}{\sqrt{a^2+h_a^2}}$

Comment: $h_a$ is also unknown

Comment: There is no way to determine the lengths of ha and hb without knowing the angle. All you can do is write an expression with two unknowns. hb = b sin(alpha) and ha = a tan(alpha)..